# redirect from subdomain to domain + .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is is possible that i can configure RewriteRule for more then one domain.

Like my requirement is 
My current domain name www.maindomain.com
and let say i have three domian and subdomain 
the subdomain url is 
example1.maindomain.com
example2.maindomain.com
example3.maindomain.com

Now i want when ever user try to access www.example1.com it should get the content of example1.maindomain.com and the same for example2, example3

I am using apache + passenger.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 10):

First, write a condition that matches all the domain names you want to redirect. Using the matched part of the domain, write a rule that rewrites to the target subdomain URLs. So, given the desired mapping stated in your question, something like the following should do the trick:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(example[123])\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%1.maindomain.com/$1 [L,R]
```

The above rewrites from e.g. `www.example1.com` to `example1.maindomain.com`. Similarly, if you need it the other way round:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(example[123])\.maindomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.%1.com/$1 [L,R]
```

This would rewrite e.g. `example2.maindomain.com` to `www.example2.com`.

Comment: Can this be done using a wildcard? Something like:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(*)\.maindomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.maindomain.com/$1 [L,R]

Comment: The above actually already contains a "wildcard": the hostname pattern in the [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteCond) is a regex, which matches `www.example1.com`, `www.example2.com`, and `www.example3.com`. You can of course use use any other regex as well. For matching any subdomain(s), `\.maindomain\.com$` should do (or, alternatively `^.*\.maindomain\.com$`).

Comment: Thanks! What I've found working is:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domain\.nl$   [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.nl/?subdomain=%1  [L,R]