# Redirect Subdomain to new domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi guys trying to get a 301 redirect working and having trouble. I need to redirect sub.domain1.com to www.domain2.com and make sure that any file names or parameters get sent over with it.

This is what I was trying:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain2.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I also tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^sub\.domain1\.com$ /www.domain2.com? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Where am I messing up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rule of thumb for rewriterules: from the most complex to the less complex.
And don't forget the QSA directive (QSA = Query String Append = "make sure that any file names or parameters get sent over with it")

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain2.com/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

Tell me if it works.

Answer (score 2):

You missed the subdomain part and proper escaping.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain1\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain2.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Further explain can be found [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321123/redirect-from-subdomain-to-domain-htaccess).