# Redirect wildcard subdomains to same subdomains on different domain without changing url

Tags: subdomain, wildcard

I have a website using wildcard subdomains.

I need to change the domain and redirect all old pages to the new domain.

For example: I want to redirect this page 
`x.olddomain.example/stackoverflow`to  `x.NewDomain.example/stackoverflow`

without making any changes on the subdomains folders.

I used this code :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+\.)?olddomain.example$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1newdomain.example%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But the result is:
`x.olddomain.example/stackoverflow`
redirectw to
`x.olddomain.example/?name=stackoverflow`

**Please note :** that the problem occurs when you try to enter the domain directly to browser .. but if you are on the subdomain it's working fine

If you are browsing the page
`x.olddomain.example`
and you clicked on this link through that page
`x.olddomain.example/stackoverflow`, then
it redirects fine to 
`x.newdomain.example/stackoverflow`

But if you tried to enter `x.olddomain.example/stackoverflow` directly through the browser it redirects to `x.newdomain.example/?name=stackoverflow`

Comment: You should check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730298/redirect-any-sub-domain-to-a-page-on-main-domain and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569399/redirect-subdomain-to-new-domain

Comment: i checked it but still not working !!!

Comment: Start by removing the space after the `ˆ`.  There is nothing in what you have shown that can do a redirection to an URL with `?name=something` in it. So you have other parts of your configuration that come into play.